# rails block a record for change for another places in the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, sidekiq

I have a ruby on rails application with a lot of sidekiq workers. Some of workers can work for a while (at least few minutes).

How can I block some record for changes from another places (ie controllers), to avoid data conflict when I save this record in the worker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to lock the model:

```
account = Account.first

account.with_lock do
  # This block is called within a transaction,
  # account is already locked.
  account.balance -= 100
  account.save!
end
```

You can read more about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html).